# Symfony3 Twig Assetic parsing error

Tags: twig, symfony, assetic

When I clear cache in prod, this error appears:

```
Twig_Error_Syntax: Lexer or parser ended up in unsupported state
```

It only happens, when I'm using named assets:

```
{% stylesheets '@bootstrap_css' %}
```

When I'm using path to resources:

```
{% stylesheets 'Resources/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css' %}
```

it's ok...

My config.yml:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        bootstrap_css:
            inputs:
                - Resources/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css
                - Resources/css/lib/bootstrap-theme.min.css
            output: compiled/css/bootstrap.css
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It happens due to this issue https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/429

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue. I defined my output in options, tried removing it and had no success. I was also using filters so thought that may have had something to do with it. It didn't.

I ended up defining the group of assets within my Twig template with the filters defined and the error stopped happening. I think it is probably a bug still today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see "outputs" listed in the [Full Default Configuration listing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html).

Try just commenting that out and see what happens.

Second edit:

Also try the full path. I see on the Symfony's assetic site there is a comment that this might not work (but I'm not sure):

{% stylesheets ''Resources/css/lib/*' %}

See the comment just below [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-css-stylesheets) as to "paths to your assest" for reference.

Comment: Updated my post - I think you need my second option.

Comment: Yep, In my primary post I wrote that option with full path is working. But error with named assets is only directly after clearing cache. After refresh everything is ok :/

Answer (score 0):

After clearing the cache, be sure to dump the assets, too:

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

This did the trick for me.